# Intento crear un objeto para llenar un arraylist pero siempre la ultima posicion sobreescribe a las demas

Tags: java, archivo, arraylist, licencias

intento lo que estoy haciendo es leer un archivo y luego guardar el contenido de ese archivo en un arraylist de un objeto, el problema es que cuando uso el objeto para guardar los valores siempre se sobre escribe el ultimo valor sobre los demás, bueno para mejor entendimiento dejo el código y su respectivo output, ojala puedan ayudarme he intentado de todo muchísimas gracias.

```
public ArrayList<Usuarios> leerArchivoUsu() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
        String contenido;
        int contUno = 0,contDos = 0;
        FileReader archivo = new FileReader("C:/Archivos Battleship/Usuarios.txt");
        try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(archivo)) {
            while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                contUno++;
                if (contUno == 2) {
                    nombre = contenido;
                }
                if (contUno == 3) {
                    apellido = contenido;
                }
                if (contUno == 4) {
                    fecha = String.valueOf(contenido);
                    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(fecha));
                }
                if (contUno == 5) {
                    user = contenido;
                }
                if (contUno == 6) {
                    pass = contenido;
                }
                if (contUno == 7) {
                    if (Integer.valueOf(contenido) > score) {
                        scoreB = Integer.valueOf(contenido);
                    } else {
                        scoreB = score;
                    }
                }
                if (contUno == 7) {
                    contUno = 0;
                    if(contDos == 0){
                        System.out.println("u");
                        u = new Usuarios(nombre,apellido,cal,user,pass,scoreB);
                        listaUsuarios.add(u);
                    }
                    if(contDos > 0){
                        System.out.println("ua");
                        u = new Usuarios();
                        u.setNombre(nombre);
                        u.setApellido(apellido);
                        u.setFechaNac(cal);
                        u.setUser(user);
                        u.setPassword(pass);
                        u.setScoreGen(scoreB);
                        listaUsuarios.add(u);
                    }
                    contDos++;
                }

            }
            archivo.close();
        }
        System.out.println(listaUsuarios.size());
        return listaUsuarios;
    }
```

y este es el output:

> ►Usuario: hfhs
>
> Puntuacion: 0
>
> ►Usuario: hfhs
>
> Puntuacion: 0
>
> ►Usuario: hfhs
>
> Puntuacion: 0
>
> ►Usuario: hfhs
>
> Puntuacion: 0
>
> ►Usuario: hfhs
>
> Puntuacion: 0

alguna manera de solucionar esto?

Comment: y que tienen que ver las licencias de software? O.o

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, al parecer toString usa variables estáticas y yo al usar toString para escribir de nuevo el archivo debía declarar tales variables en la clase también estáticas, la solución fue crear un objecto dentro de la clase donde llamo el toString para editarlo  ya poder usar variables no estáticas. ejemplo :

```
@override
public String toString() {
        return "\n" + Persona.getNombre() + 
               "\n" + Persona.getApellido() +
               "\n" + String.valueOf(Persona.getFechaNac().getTime()) +
               "\n" + user +
               "\n" + password +
               "\n" + scoreGen + "\n";
    }
```

esto hereda de una clase persona  a una clase usuario, las variables que uso son no estáticas, pero la clase Persona al parecer si, la solución:

````
Persona p = new Persona();
@override
public String toString() {
        return "\n" + p.getNombre() + 
               "\n" + p.getApellido() +
               "\n" + String.valueOf(p.getFechaNac().getTime()) +
               "\n" + user +
               "\n" + password +
               "\n" + scoreGen + "\n";
    }```
````